# How can I add color to a select list in Webpage?

Tags: html, css, html-table, styles, background-color

I am using the html code below. However, I am only able to get the color around "our recommended favorites" text. The select tag reads from javascript file to create a list of options. Even when I put the background color in the select tag, it oes not chnage anything.  The image below is the result I get. 
`<th width= 20% style="background-color: #4472C4">

      <label>
        <h2>Our Recommended Favorites</h2>
        <select bgcolor="#4472C4" size=20 id="myList" class="list-content" onchange="setPicture();">
        </select>
      </label>

    </th>`
However, this does no add color to cell. I have tried adding bg command to  tag as well, however it does not work. Any suggestions? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```html
<th width= 20% style="background-color: #4472C4">

      <label>
        <h2>Our Recommended Favorites</h2>
        <select style="background-color:4472C4" size=20 id="myList" class="list-content" onchange="setPicture();">
         
        </select>
      </label>

    </th>
```

Comment: you are rendering list option with dynamically with js so please try 
$("#myList").css("background-color","#4472C4");

Answer (score 0):

I usally style the HTML outside of the HTML page, and link it with command, try to add 
display: block;if it doesnt work , i would like to see the entire code, and what are you trying to do extacly?

Answer (score 0):

style="background-color: #4472C4"

Comment: to which tag, label or select? cause it doesn't work either.

Comment: @shvan to the select